# Using radix sort/counting sort for array of structs in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, radix-sort, counting-sort

I have an array of structs which contains a uint32_t type. With knowing the max and min value of the array, I want to implement counting sort or radix sort to sort the array based on the uint32_t. The range of the values may be very large.  I have no idea how to sort an array of structs instead of integers. Or are there any better algorithms for such sorting? Thanks!

Comment: First: implement a simpler sort such as bubble sort using structs containing an int.  Once you figure out how to do that, you can move on to radix sort.  Don't try to do everything in one step.

Comment: If your structures contain members other than the `uint32_t` you want to use as the sort key then a standard Counting Sort is out of the question, as it relies on the indistinguishability of integers having the same value.  If the range of values is large, as you say, then probably Counting Sort is a poor idea anyway, because it scales as O(R+N) in time and memory, where R is the *range* of the values being sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/), you need to provide a comparison function, like this

```
struct Foo
{ 
   uint32_t index;
   other stuff;
}


int compareMyType (const void * a_, const void * b_)
{
  const Foo* a = a_;
  const Foo* b = b_;

  if ( a->index <  b->index ) return -1;
  if ( a->index == b->index ) return 0;
  if ( a->index >  b->index ) return 1;
}

Foo foos[100];
qsort(foos,100,compareMyType );
```

A radix sort might be faster for integers, but if you are really concerned about  efficiency, you would not sort an array of structs, but an array of pointers to structs, since there will be substantial overhead in copying the data around.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did implement the qsort with comparison function. But how to implement radix sort to sort the array of pointers?

Comment: In a radix sort, you create N bins, and loop over the array and put each element into one of the bins (based on the digit you are sorting on), then merge the bins back together. Repeat this for each digit until done. In your case, instead of putting the *integer* into the bin, you put the *pointer* into the bin.

Answer (score 0):

Do a counting radix sort one byte of the 32 bit integer at a time (note this has to be done least significant byte first, most significant byte last). It will take sort 4 passes to sort the array. You'll need a second array to move to / from for each pass of the radix sort.

You'll save a bit of time by using a 4 (each 32 bit integer has 4 bytes) x 256 (each byte has 256 possible values) matrix of indices (initially these are counts, but converted to indices), filling in the matrix with just one pass of the array.

So that's a total of 5 read passes and 4 write passes of the array of structures using a counting / radix sort based on the 4 bytes of the 32 bit integer values.